# Pay during Notice period

Tags: united-kingdom

I have given my employer a month notice whilst on furlough. I worked as a bar manager but started a new job a week after I handed my notice in. My old employer is refusing to pay me my months notice as they have asked me to work even though they not open for business. They are saying they can make me come to work to provide training for the new management and a smooth transition for when they can resume trading.
I can’t work the hours in my old job as it conflicts with the hours I’m doing in my new job

Comment: "but started a new job a week after I handed my notice in"  Why did you hand in a months notice if you were going to start working somewhere else a week into it?

Answer (score 7):

> I can’t work the hours in my old job as it conflicts with the hours I’m doing in my new job

Then by definition, you cannot work your old job. You did not hand in your notice, you quit. With little to no notice. Asking to be paid for both jobs at the same time is probably close to fraud depending on your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 0):

"Pacta sunt servanda." - Agreements must be kept/fulfilled.

"Everyone has the right to work, to free choice of employment, to just and favourable conditions of work and to protection against unemployment." Article 23 sentence 1 of the Universal Declaration of Human Rights.

On one side, you may work as much as you wish and be employed as often as you want.

On the other side, you have to fulfill the duties of the employment contracts. If you are working at one employer and the other employer calls you in, than you have to break the conditions of either contract.

You are entitled to all pays of all employment contracts you enter. Same as you are liable of not fulfilling any employment contract.

From a basic view of law, you are eligible for pay by the one employer that refuses to pay you. This is because until today no cause has happened that you violated the employment contract. Employment contracts may also not forbid to enter other employments at the same time, because of the "Right to work" by the Universal Declaration of Human Rights.

However you could be held liable resulting from damages not fulfilling your employment contract, in the case you get called in. (Worst case: immediate termination of that contract)

(Social security and taxes can be affected differently though.)

Comment: The Universal Declaration of Human Rights is *not* legally binding.

Comment: "Employment contracts may also not forbid to enter other employments at the same time, because of the "Right to work" by the Universal Declaration of Human Rights" That is fundamentally wrong. There are all kinds of reasons why you cannot work two contracts, the most basic that one of them forbids working for a competitor, or maybe just because they have the same timetable or maybe you aren't even allowed to work two shifts in a row if you aren't self employed in countries that have worker protection.

Comment: You seem to fantasize all kinds of things into this one paragraph. Free choice of employment is severely limited by the existing laws. Simple example: I cannot go and be the hitman for an agency specializing in tax fraud. Why? Because it's *illegal*. Likewise for many things you claimed. Being furloughed in the UK is a concept that we do not have 1:1 but we have "Kurzarbeit". That does *not* mean you can work two jobs and get twice the money. That would be fraud.

Comment: "Right to work" has been implemented differently in various countries.